# onRegisterApi function not being called, ui-grid

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid

I am trying to display the table using ui-grid. The table is being displayed fine but without calling onRegisterApi function. I didnt even notice it as the table display worked fine until I wanted to use vm.gridApi.core.refresh() method. When I added that method, it gave me vm.gridApi undefined error.

My controller looks like this:

```
function userEventData (resp) {
            $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: resp.results["@href"]
            }).success(function (responseData) {
                logger.info("userEventData responseData", responseData);
                vm.gridOptions.data = responseData;
                logger.info("gridOptions", vm.gridOptions.data);
                poulateGrid();
                //return responseData;
            });
        }

function populateGrid () {
            logger.info("populateGrid function activated");
            vm.dateFormat = "medium";
            var temp = vm.gridOptions.data;
            vm.gridOptions = {
                enableColumnMenu: true,
                enableFiltering: true,
                enableSelectAll: true,
                rowTemplate: gridService.getRowTemplate(),
                excludeProperties: ["meta"],
                onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
                    logger.info("onRegisterApi activated");
                    vm.gridApi = gridApi;
                    logger.info("vm.gridApi when defined", vm.gridApi);
                    vm.gridApi.grid.registerRowsProcessor(vm.singleFilter(), 200 );
                },
                columnDefs: [
                    {
                        field: "sun",
                        displayName: "Init User",
                        allowCellFocus: false,
                        enableGrouping: true,
                    },
                    {
                        field: "dun",
                        displayName: "Target User",
                        allowCellFocus: false,

                    },
                    {
                        field: "evt",
                        displayName: "Name",
                        allowCellFocus: false
                    },
                    {
                        field: "dip",
                        displayName: "What is affected",
                        allowCellFocus: false
                    },
                    {
                        field: "det",
                        displayName: "Time created",
                        allowCellFocus: false,
                        cellFilter: "date:grid.appScope.vm.dateFormat"
                    }
                ]

            }
```

html

> `<div ui-grid="vm.gridOptions" style="padding-top: 1%;">`

Any idea why this is happening? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are calling the populateGrid() function after you have already initialized  vm.gridOptions.data  with the data from your HTTP request.

Try reordering your code to do something like this:

```
vm.gridOptions = {}; // must have gridOptions defined first

function userEventData (resp) {
            $http({
                method: "GET",
                url: resp.results["@href"]
            }).success(function (responseData) {
                logger.info("userEventData responseData", responseData);
                logger.info("gridOptions", vm.gridOptions.data);
                populateGrid(); // call this first
                vm.gridOptions.data = responseData; // now you can load the data
                //return responseData;
            });
        }

function populateGrid () {
            logger.info("populateGrid function activated");
            vm.dateFormat = "medium";
            // var temp = vm.gridOptions.data; // this wont exist yet
            vm.gridOptions = {
                enableColumnMenu: true,
                enableFiltering: true,
                enableSelectAll: true,
                rowTemplate: gridService.getRowTemplate(),
                excludeProperties: ["meta"],
                onRegisterApi: function (gridApi) {
                    logger.info("onRegisterApi activated");
                    vm.gridApi = gridApi;
                    logger.info("vm.gridApi when defined", vm.gridApi);
                    vm.gridApi.grid.registerRowsProcessor(vm.singleFilter(), 200 );
                },
                columnDefs: [
                    {
                        field: "sun",
                        displayName: "Init User",
                        allowCellFocus: false,
                        enableGrouping: true,
                    },
                    {
                        field: "dun",
                        displayName: "Target User",
                        allowCellFocus: false,

                    },
                    {
                        field: "evt",
                        displayName: "Name",
                        allowCellFocus: false
                    },
                    {
                        field: "dip",
                        displayName: "What is affected",
                        allowCellFocus: false
                    },
                    {
                        field: "det",
                        displayName: "Time created",
                        allowCellFocus: false,
                        cellFilter: "date:grid.appScope.vm.dateFormat"
                    }
                ]
            }
            }
```